# Is asynchronous socket handling the way i need to go? In Python

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, udp

So i been readying for a awhile now. And it seems like asynchronous socket handling would be a better approach to dealing with what I'm trying to do.

Right now I'm working on a gaming server. At the moment socket server will do ok with about 3 clients or so. Sending data at the same exact time.

But my problem is, after that things start to get laggy. So if i do a asynchronous server in the same manner to what i'm already doing. Would it make the game data transfer more smoothly? 
This is in python by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous sockets are more effective then synchronous. But if the game is lagging for 4+ clients, then your server/client system is badly written and it is not the matter of sockets imho.

Comment: I clicked on the checkmark on the answers that was the most helpfull to me. Hope that was what you mean by accepting answersp

Comment: @Shane Obviously you receive and broadcast data from server. But if the server is lagging it means that you receive and send way too much data. It seems that you send some unnecessary data or the data is not compressed. Or the server is like 20 years old and it cannot handle it. :)

Comment: Well i am just a newbie at this networking stuff. But, i'm trying to learn. As of right now, i have the server setup to keep the players updated of their position. So like, right now, when ever a person moves. The position is sent to the server. And relayed right back to everyone that's connected. And i'm just sending the data through a pickle.

Comment: It is hard to say anything without code. Show us some server and client code. Of course only the relevant part.